# Content Security Policy (CSP) - Problem with dynamic inline style during OneTrust integration

Tags: javascript, cookies, content-security-policy, inline-styles, one-trust

I am integrating a cookie tool - OneTrust. I add them by adding scripts in the `<head>` of the html page. The scripts call other scripts and create inline styles.

I manage to embrace all scripts by adding a 'nonce' to this scripts. I have a problem with **inline styles** which are created on the CDN domain of the OneTrust tool.

Is it possible to load scripts that contain dynamically injected inline styles with the `style-src 'self'` set in the Content Security Policy (CSP)?

Has anyone resolved a similar problem yet or is the only solution to add an `'unsafe-inline'` directive to the `style-src` in CSP?

Comment: What does "*inline styles on the cdn domain*" mean?

Answer (score 1):

OneTrust now has a "preview" feature where you can provide a [nonce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce) for your script, but it has to be enabled by their support team.

```
<script nonce="PPAjsdRsCmdup5UwtyLkdg==" src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js"" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="XXXXXXX" ></script>
```

https://developer.onetrust.com/onetrust/docs/content-security-policy-cdn